# Why does GetQueryNameValuePairs remove square brackets?

Tags: c#, rest, http

I pass an HTTP query like

```
http://x.com/myapi?myparam[a]=xy&myparam[bc]=z
```

to my own Rest API.

In the controller (System.Web.Http.ApiController) calling `Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()` returns two `KeyValuePair<string, string>` objects with the keys `myparam.a` and `myparam.bc`.

Why don't I get `myparam[a]` and `myparam[bc]` as keys?

I'm using System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.GetQueryNameValuePairs() from Assembly System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.7.0 which NuGet installs into ...\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll

**Edit**
I found out that it depends on the value in the brackets:

| param | key |
| --- | --- |
| p[a] | p.a |
| p[ab] | p.ab |
| p[1] | p[1] |
| p[23.4] | p[23.4] |
| p[23.4x] | p[23.4x] |
| p[y23.4x] | p.y23.4x |

But is there any docu around?

Comment: Seems a little X/Yish why do you need to do this? Have you tried encoding the brackets?

Comment: @TheGeneral I have a API for searching. With a query like that I can return all results which match either myparam = xy or myparam = z.
My previous version uses Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.dll. There the square brackets are passed in the keys.

Comment: @TheGeneral: And yes, they are encoded. In the controller the Request.RequestUri.OriginalString contains ...?myparam%5ba%5d=a&myparam%5bbc%5d=z